# Background image not rendering from external CSS file to .php -- works perfectly with .html (body tags)

Tags: php, html, css

So I'm trying to have a background image for all pages of my website.  I did this using an external css file and it worked perfectly when I looked at my project in .html form.  I need to now use PHP in my code so I have transferred my html files to PHP set up a localhost etc.  Now when I view the website from the local host everything is styled exactly how it was supposed to with the exception of a background image.  I'm not sure how to pull this background image from my external css and link it to my .php so that the background image also renders.  The background is just plain white instead of the background photo I have desired.

Below is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>PlexQ</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CretanQ/styles/style.css">
<script src="scripts/form.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- NavBar -->
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="images/cretanq.png" alt="Cretan Logo" width="180px" height="75px">
  </div>
 </nav>

<!-- Registration Pop-up (Hidden) -->
<div class="pop_container" id="register_pop">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <h1>Registration</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Fill in this information to create an account.</li>
      <li>Please allow up to 24 hours for email invitation to CretnVision upon approval. 
    </li>
    </ul>

    <label for="uname"><b>Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Last" name="uname" required>

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" id="psw" required>

    <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" id="psw-repeat"      required>


    <button type="submit" onclick="openPop()">Register!</button>
    <button type="submit" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
  </form>
  </div>

<!-- Registration Confirmed Popup (Hidden)-->
<div class="pop_container" id="confirm_pop">
  <form action="/Users/domenicorocca/CretanQueue/login.html">
    <h2>Registration Complete</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Invitation to CretnVision will be sent via re-mail which was used to complete       registration upon approval.</li>
    </ul>

    <button type="submit" onclick="home()">Login!</button>
  </form>
</div>

 <!-- Login Box -->
<div class="container" id="login_container">
  <form action="action_page.php" method="post">

    <label for="email"><b>E-mail</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ex: stranger@email.com" name="email" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>


      <button type="submit" id="login_button">Login</button>
      <button class="register" onclick="openRegister()">Register!</button>
      <span id="psw"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></span>

  </form>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is my stylesheet referencing my  tags:

```
body {background-image: url(images/background1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Your css is wrong: this is correct:
background: url(images/background1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;

Answer (score -1):

Since your .php file is located in root folder and css file located in /CretanQ/styles/style.css you have to use correct image location on your css. You can debug first to be sure if your image is correctly linked. Go to you page console, in google chrome click right button and click Inspect (Ctrl+Shift+I) and Click Elements and Click on  then see Styles in right bottom corner. you will see your css body class. Cursor hover on (images/background1.jpg). if you see your image on hover then its ok,but i think you wont see your image there. because you incorrectly locate the file. you have to use ../ before link/ so your style code will be something like this:

```
body {background: url(../images/background1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: so when I go to inspect element on my browser I see the styling section and when I change my file location to (../images/background1.jpg) right in the browser's inspect element section my background picture pops up.  But when I try to make this same change to my source code in my css file nothing happens.  Its blowing my mind.

Comment: Even though I edited my code to match yours above which worked in the inspect element panel as well.  Whenever I refresh my page and inspect element it still brings up this file path --  url(/Users/domenicorocca/CretanQueue/images/background1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed

Comment: @cheattowin77 thats mean your source code is not exactly as you said.you should see exactly (background: url(../images/background1.jpg) in your console too. alternatively you can try 3dots (background: url(.../images/background1.jpg) since your css file is under 2 subfolder.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out apparently it was linked to a different stylesheet... the basic of the basic of mistakes.
Thanks for your time.